# How to add custom validation message on field name without field name as a prefix?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using

```
validates_presence_of :name, :message => "promo code required"
```

it gives

```
Name promo code required
```

I want only

```
promo code required
```

Comment: try with a custom validation, and add the error to `base`

Comment: Looks for the lines of code which render the message, then customize it: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.9/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#working_with_validation_errors-errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a custom validation, and add the error message to the record as a whole, instead of a particular attribute as follows:

```
validate :name_is_present

private

# Making this private is optional, but recommended
def name_is_present
  errors.add(:base, "Promo code required") if name.blank?
end
```

For more details, refer to the explanation in [Ruby guides here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#errors-base)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use define the "humanized" name for each attribute as follows:

```
  def self.human_attribute_name(attribute, options={})
    case attribute
    when :name, "name"
       ""
    else
     super
    end
  end
```

Comment: even this works, it's not good since it'll effect other features and also make others confuse (include you in future :D.)

Comment: I see what you're getting at, but if you look through the rails source code, it's only ever used in support of `I18n`. I say pick your poison, but I would prefer this to reimplementing all of the validators as in the accepted answer. There is another option here in the rails source code using the en.yml file instead of a method. See https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/activerecord/lib/active_record/locale/en.yml#L43

Comment: I thought of a 3rd way. You could call the validators individually in your custom validate method. Like so: `ActiveModel::Validations::PresenceValidator.new({attributes: [:base]}).validate_each(record, :base, record.name)`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom validation method for this.

```
validate :promo_require

def promo_require
  errors.add(:base, 'promo code required') unless name.present?
end
```

Answer (score 0):

For newer versions of Rails (>= 6.0), you can define the `format` in locale files on model or attribute level, as described in [this article](https://www.bigbinary.com/blog/rails-6-allows-to-override-the-activemodel-errors-full_message-format-at-the-model-level-and-at-the-attribute-level):

```yaml
en:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        your_model:
          format: "%{attribute} %{message}"
          name:
            format: "%{message}"
```

Comment: Note that you have to set `config.active_model.i18n_customize_full_message` to true to enable this feature. And the i18n key is: `"activerecord.errors.models.#{model_name}.attributes.#{column_name}.format"`